# Accord.Net Implementation of weather scenario

Tags: hidden-markov-models, markov-chains, accord.net

I am trying to implement a prediction application for weather based on hidden markov models, using the accord framework. I am having some trouble on how to map the concepts into HMM structures and would like to get some insights. I am starting off with their sample application that can be found here: https://github.com/accord-net/framework/tree/master/Samples/Statistics/Gestures%20(HMMs)

Imagine the following scenario:

I am told every 6 hours what the weather is like: Cloudy, Sunny or Rainy. These would be my states in the framework correct?

Besides that, I have access to results of two different instruments, which are an air humidity meter and a wind speed meter. For simplicity, let's assume that both instruments provide a measure from 0 to 100, with 4 ranges. I would have something like 0, 1, 2 and 3 for observations regarding the humidity (0-25, 26-50, 51-75, 76-100) and the same ranges for wind would have values 4, 5, 6 and 7. These would be my observable values for sequences.

For a couple of days, I store the observations made regarding those two instruments, and based on that I will save the data for future usage, for learning purposes.

One of the questions I have is regarding timing. Since I plan to know states at every 6 hours, does it make sense or is it possible to store observations regarding instruments at a different rate? For example, if I stored observations of the instruments at every hour, I would end up with a 12 element sequence and the corresponding state, something like this for the first 12 hours:

```
0-4-0-5-0-4-1-7-1-6-0-4 - Cloudy
0-4-0-5-0-4-0-4-0-5-0-4 - Sunny
```

The 12 element sequence would be:
First hour observation of humidity - observation of wind speed (0-4)
Second hour observation of humidity - observation of wind speed (0-5)
and so on...

Should I, besides observation sequences and states, use labels for each of the instruments? Something like this:

```
0-0-0-1-1-0 - Humidity - Cloudy
4-5-4-4-5-4 - Wind Sp  - Sunny
0-0-0-1-1-0 - Humidity - Cloudy
4-5-4-4-5-4 - Wind Sp  - Sunny
```

The labels would be the instruments that were being measured, the sequences would be the observed values, and the states would be the state at the end of each 6 hours.

With this, I would like to be able to feed this information back to the model and predict the next state. Am I approaching this problem correctly? Would I be able to do what I need like this?

Thank you.